# innerHTML tag not rendering the string starts with < character

Tags: html, angular

`<div class="actual-messagediv w-p-100" [innerHTML]="referencemsgobj"></div>`

when I send some text messages starts with < character (string) it's not render either display, I'm using InnerHTML for binding data in angular 7[image: my component displays nothing after bind]

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: check this link "https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-playground-yoaygl?file=src/app/app.component.ts" i display dynamic data

Comment: Hi Ravi Ashara actually my binding dynamic value like this

referencemsgobj = '<Test String'

can you render this and show the binding value?

Comment: try this "<div class="actual-messagediv w-p-100">{{ referencemsgobj }}</div>" instead of innerHTML

Comment: also check stackblitz link i update code

Comment: test <br> <br>data  ... it render with html tags

i'm receiving dynamic data which is user defined .. when they send input with line space it displays <br> tags

Comment: So in this case you need to remove "<" in your string from starting

Comment: that's fine .. what if they want to send string like passwords for example <#123.... if i remove that character means receiver receive only #123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You might have to replace the less than symbol with it's equivalent [HTML entity](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref). For `<` symbol you could use `&lt;`.

```js
const value = '< some value';
const entity = value.replace('<', '&lt;');
```

2. In Angular, if you know the HTML is safe to be bound, it's also better to sanitize it using the [`DomSanitizer`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustHtml).

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div [innerHTML]="referencemsgobj"></div>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  referencemsgobj: SafeHtml;

  constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.referencemsgobj = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
      '<some value'.replace('<', '&lt;')
    );
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x9ec3u?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you so much Micheal D , it's working exactly what i expected